# How to load same page while clicking browser back button after logout the application

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I invalidated the session  and removed all session variables in logout method and clear cache and history.

I already tried the following ways

1-used this code to clear the cache control and used window.history.forward()

```
HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); 
        httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); 
        httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```

2-used this code in jsp loader method

```
function disableBack() { window.history.forward() }
        window.onload = disableBack();
        window.onpageshow = function(evt) { if (evt.persisted) disableBack() }
```

3- used this code also

```
window.history.forward();function noBack(){window.history.forward();}
```

I didn't get a proper solution for this problem.

these codes all are working fine and also its not allowed to go previous pages.

If i logout the application the i don't want to go previous pages, how can  disabled the browser back button property after logout the application?

Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: It's seems a server-side problem instead of javascript. If you logout and then you hit the back button, you must check for session validity: if the session is expired or there's no session at all, you must redirect to login page.

Comment: Please don't try to break my browsers' UX - it's the wrong solution.